# Finding filled rectangles given x, y coordinates using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry

Given the following filled x, y coordinates:

```
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
1, 0 
1, 1
1, 2
2, 0
2, 1
2, 2
4, 0
4, 1
5, 0
5, 1
```

How do I write an SQL query to determine all the filled rectangles? A rectangle is defined by its top left and bottom right corners.

Desired Results

```
x1 | y1 | x2 | y2 
 0    0   2    2 
 0    4   1    5
```

Because

```
+---+---+---+---+
|   | 0 | 1 | 2 |
+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | X | X | X |
| 1 | X | X | X |
| 2 | X | X | X |
| 3 |   |   |   |
| 4 | X | X |   |
| 5 | X | X |   |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: What RDBMS? What are the desired results for your example data?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?

Comment: Does this sequence of XY coordinates represent a path for a filled polygon?

Comment: @user986779 - Are you using the postgres [geometry datatype](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-geometry.html)?

Comment: @MartinSmith no the query needs to work without using that.

Comment: @user986779 - What if `(2,2)` wasn't there? It would then be ambiguous what the result should be?

Comment: @MartinSmith then it would result in 2 smaller rectangles being formed. One ending at 1,2 and one ending at 2,1. Both starting at 0,0. The rectangles can overlap.

Comment: There was a mistake in the coordinates of the second rectangle in the desired results that I have just fixed.

Comment: Just a nit-pick, in your example data x goes up to 5, but in your desired result y goes up to 5.  Doesn't change the fundamentals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting puzzle, solution edited with ideas from ypercube's answer:

```
declare @t table (x int, y int);
insert @t (x,y) values (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0),  (1, 1), (1, 2), 
                       (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (4, 0), (4, 1), (5, 0), (5, 1);

; with  all_rectangles as
        (
        select  lt.x as x1
        ,       lt.y as y1
        ,       rt.x as x2
        ,       lb.y as y2
        from    @t lt -- Left top
        join    @t rt -- Right top
        on      rt.y = lt.y -- Must share top
                and rt.x > lt.x
        join    @t lb -- Left bottom
        on      lb.x = lt.x -- Must share left
                and lb.y > lt.y
        join    @t rb -- Right bottom (limits resultset)
        on      rb.x = rt.x -- Must share right
                and rb.y = lb.y -- Must share bottom
        )
,       filled_rectangles as
        (
        select  rect.x1
        ,       rect.y1
        ,       rect.x2
        ,       rect.y2
        from    all_rectangles rect
        join    @t crossed
        on      crossed.x between rect.x1 and rect.x2
                and crossed.y between rect.y1 and rect.y2
        group by
                rect.x1
        ,       rect.y1
        ,       rect.x2
        ,       rect.y2
        having  count(*) = 
                (rect.x2 - rect.x1 + 1) * (rect.y2 - rect.y1 + 1)
        )
select  *
from    filled_rectangles rect
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    filled_rectangles bigger
        where   bigger.x1 <= rect.x1 and rect.x2 <= bigger.x2
                and bigger.y1 <= rect.y1 and rect.y2 <= bigger.y2
                and (rect.x1 <> bigger.x1 or rect.x2 <> bigger.x2 
                or rect.y1 <> bigger.y1 or rect.y2 <> bigger.y2)
        );
```

It first builds a list of all possible rectangles.  Then it demands that the number of filled positions matches the total number of positions (the area of the rectangle.)  Finally, it demands that there's no other rectangle that entirely covers the rectangle.

You might have to adopt it for PostgreSQL, but the idea should work.

Comment: Was about to try and convert this to PostgreSQL until ypercube posted the solution below. Thank you for taking the time to do this though!

Comment: ypercube suggested that you get the credit for the accepted answer because his solution was very similar to yours :)

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH Box AS
( SELECT LeftUp.X     AS x1
       , LeftUp.Y     AS y1
       , RightDown.X  AS x2
       , RightDown.Y  AS y2
  FROM TableX AS LeftUp
    JOIN TableX AS LeftDown
      ON  LeftDown.X = LeftUp.X
      AND LeftDown.Y >= LeftUp.Y
    JOIN TableX AS RightUp
      ON  RightUp.Y = LeftUp.Y
      AND RightUp.X >= LeftUp.X
    JOIN TableX AS RightDown
      ON  RightDown.X = RightUp.X
      AND RightDown.Y = LeftDown.Y
    JOIN TableX AS Inside
      ON  Inside.X BETWEEN LeftUp.X AND RightDown.X
      AND Inside.Y BETWEEN LeftUp.Y AND RightDown.Y
  GROUP BY LeftUp.X
         , LeftUp.Y
         , RightDown.X
         , RightDown.Y
  HAVING COUNT(*) = (1 + RightDown.X - LeftUp.X) * (1 + RightDown.Y - LeftUp.Y)
)

SELECT B.*
FROM Box AS B                         --- SmallBox (but not very small)
WHERE NOT EXISTS                      --- as there not exists
        ( SELECT *                    --- any
          FROM Box AS BB              --- BigBox
          WHERE BB.x1 <= B.x1         --- that covers the "small" one
            AND BB.x2 >= B.x2
            AND BB.y1 <= B.y1
            AND BB.y2 >= B.y2
            AND (BB.x1, BB.x2, BB.y1, BB.y2) <> (B.x1, B.x2, B.y1, B.y2)
        )
```

Comment: Wow, that's one complex query. Works perfectly, thanks. Now going to try and understand it!

Comment: TheNuke: I think @Andomar deserves the accepted answer. he answered first, my query is very similar and he has added a lot of explaining how it works.

Comment: I love this community! Will give him the credit on your request.

Comment: @Andomar: thnx. I was wondering if we could somehow get rid of the `GROUP BY` and the `HAVING COUNT(*) = ...` check.

Comment: I like how this solution only tries rectangles with corners at filled positions. +1

Comment: @ypercube Nice answer...! could you explain how did you get that answer?? How did you reason to finally write this query?

Comment: @JuanPabloContreras: I can try but you understand that I wrote this about a year ago.